# Find all action methods that have been decorated with [OutputCache] and remove

Tags: c#, caching, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to find all Action methods on all controllers that have been decorated with `[OutputCache]` so I can then enumerate through them to remove `selected` items from the cache in one go?

```
foreach(var .. in ...)
{
  //get ActionName
  //get ControllerName
  HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem(Url.Action(ActionName, ControllerName));
}
```

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782569/invalidate-the-whole-output-cache-in-asp-net-mvc-2) it is not possible to invalidate the cache in one go.

**Edit** It looks like I can invalidate the `ALL` the cache by simply doing this:-

```
public ActionResult Invalidate()
{
    OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache = new MemoryCache("NewDefault");
    return View();
}
```

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326230/mvc3-outputcache-removeoutputcacheitem-renderaction) for more info. However it would be nice to invalidate portions of the cache depending say on controller name etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
public ActionResult Invalidate()
{
    OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache = new MemoryCache("NewDefault");
    return View();
}
```

has done the trick...